# Il sera fait réponse

Tags: expressions

— À laquelle **il sera fait réponse** par de l’or, dit Fouquet en faisant un signe à son intendant, qui aussitôt partit avec le bon que lui tendait d’Artagnan.

([lien](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Dumas_-_Le_Vicomte_de_Bragelonne,_1876.djvu/751))

Est-ce que cette tournure est correcte ? Je vois peu d'exemples sur Internet.

Answer (score 3):

Oui, bien sûr, c'est correct. Dumas n'allait pas mettre du français non standard dans la bouche de Fouquet. C'est en revanche très littéraire et était déjà considéré comme vieilli il y a cent ans.

TLFI [**Réponse**](https://cnrtl.fr/definition/r%C3%A9ponse)

> ♦ Faire réponse (vieilli). *« (...) Il ne vous fait même pas réponse quand on lui cause », ajoutait Françoise qui disait « faire réponse », comme Mme de Sévigné* (Proust, *Le côté de Guermantes II*, 1921, p. 23).

Comment: Je pensais à une faute de frappe. J'ai vu cette tournure sur le site d'une revue ou d'une médiathèque.

Comment: C'est un peu un équivalent littéraire du fameux ["la question elle est vite répondue"](https://www.20minutes.fr/high-tech/2809411-20200628-question-vite-repondue-petite-phrase-influenceur-jp-fanguin-devient-slogan-publicitaire)